# Is there a way to catch and re-interpret a GridView update event when tied to an XmlDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a *GridView* tied to an *XmlDataSource* to take advantage of the edit/update/delete capabilities *GridView* inherently offers.  *XmlDataSource* offers no update event handling so that must be performed manually.  I have no problem with this.

My problem is how/where can I catch this update event to perform my custom handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you handle the

```
protected void grvFoo_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Calling

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

Eg

```
protected void grvFoo_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Your XML update code here

        //Cancel the gridview calling the update
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

And on in the grids columns either have

> asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"

Or a Button, within a template field, which CommandName = "Update" as this should trigger that event also.

Comment: Yeh that totally works setting e.Cancel = true for the RowUpdating event handler.  Thanks alot for the feedback Jammin.